# Stripping the time out of datetime SQL Server 2005

Tags: function, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I think I'm going crazy here.

I am trying to do a SP on SQL Server 2005 which takes a date, looks it up in another table and assigns a period number and week number (for financial calendar purposes).

The output needs to hold the date as a string, rather than datetime.

I simply CANNOT get the date to show without the time behind it.

I have tried a couple of methods:

```
select cast(floor(cast(@CalcDate as float)) as datetime)
```

I have made a function which converts it into a string and puts it back out again:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DateToVarchar (@DateIn datetime)
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
declare @DD [varchar] (2)
declare @MM [varchar] (2)
declare @YYYY [varchar] (4)
declare @DateOut [varchar] (10)
declare @DDLen [int]
declare @MMLen [int]

set @DD = datepart(dd,@DateIn)
set @DDLen = len(@DD)
set @DD = (case when @DDLen < 2 then '0' + @DD else @DD end)

set @MM = datepart(mm,@DateIn)
set @MMLen = len(@MM)
set @MM = (case when @MMLen < 2 then '0' + @MM else @MM end)

set @YYYY = datepart(yyyy,@DateIn)

set @DateOut = @YYYY + '-' + @MM + '-' + @DD

return @DateOut

END
```

When I run the above function outside of the SP I get the date back just fine. When I run it through the SP it comes back as 2012-12-30 00:00:00.000

The variable @CalcDate is declared as a varchar(10)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

***EDIT***

Here is the body of the SP so far:

```
declare @StartDate [datetime]
,   @EndDate [Datetime]
,   @CalcDate [datetime] --This number will change in the WHILE loop to reflect the increment of days
,   @Week [varchar]
,   @Period [varchar]
,   @i [int]
,   @Year [int]
,   @CalcDay [int]
,   @CalcMonth [int]
,   @CalcYear [int]
,   @ConcatDate [char] (10)

set @StartDate = '2012-12-30'
set @EndDate = '2013-01-28'
set @Year = 2013
set @i = -1

-- Going to do a while loop here and instead of Week number and Period Number I'm going to do some calculations
set @Week = (Select WeekNum from aaGreensPeriodListTest Where PeriodNum = 1 and WeekNum = 1)
set @Period = (Select PeriodNum from aaGreensPeriodListTest Where PeriodNum = 1 and WeekNum = 1)
set @CalcDate = @StartDate + @i

set @CalcMonth = datepart(mm,@calcdate)

insert into aaGreensPeriodTest(RealDate,GreensYear,GreensPeriod,GreensWeek)
values (@CalcDate,@Year,@Period,@Week)

select @CalcDate as CalcDate, @CalcMonth as CalcMonth
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Could you post the code - or relevant part - of the SP where you're using the result?

Comment: @Ic Edited OP to show the SP as it stands. It's still in very rough draft.

Comment: @AlisonWonderland Starting to feel like I'm missing something since I can't see you converting the date using the function in your SP, but how is the output value declared on the SP? As `DATETIME` or `VARCHAR`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Apologies: I took the Function call out of my SP because it wasn't working within the SP, only as a standalone.

Comment: OK - I apologise to everyone: I have found my mistake. I declared @CalcDate as datetime and I was using that to define the output of the function and so I ended up with.... DATETIME.

Really sorry, and thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 does not support date type without time part.
If your need to get date as a string you can use convert function. For example:

```
declare @date datetime;
set @date = getdate();
select convert(varchar, @date, 101) -- that will return date in ‘mm/dd/yyyy’ format
```

If you need a datetime variable without time part for some calculations, you can use an expression below:

```
declare @date datetime;
set @date = getdate();
select dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, @date), 0)
```

Comment: @Alison Wonderland: To expand on Andrey's answer, the `datetime` data type has no inherent format. As the name suggests, it is always date *and* time. When you assign a string formatted as a date without the time part to a datetime variable, the latter's time part is automatically set to `00:00`. How you see a datetime in the output depends on the software you are using to view the results. If the software you use cannot interpret a `00:00` datetime as a pure date as you seem to want, you need to convert the value into a string *immediately before* returning it.

Answer (score 0):

As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187928.aspx, you cannot cast float->date directly. It's simply not supporte. But you can cast a datetime->date, so you'll have to double-cast. Or given your example, triple-cast:

```
CAST(CAST(CAST(@CalcDate AS float) AS datetime) AS date)
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc B - SQL Server 2005 doesn't support the type of "date" sadly.

Should I use datetime in there instead of date?

Comment: if you use datetime, then you are going to get time values. I guess go throw a pie at BillCo for not support plain date fields...